# How can I group by 2 fields and having by an interval type?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum, intervals, having

I've got this table:

```
TABLE T (
id int, 
month int,
interval hours
);
```

and I want to group by id and month, and add the hours.
For example:

```
id  month  hours
-------------------
 1  1      08:00:00  
 1  1      09:00:00 
 1  2      10:00:00 
 1  2      11:00:00
```

I want:

```
1 1  17:00:00
1 2  21:00:00
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM T 
GROUP BY T.id , T.month
HAVING SUM( SELECT EXTRACT ( epoch FROM T.hours ) / 3600 );
```

but it doens't work and I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  id,
  month,
  sum(extract ('epoch' from hours)/3600)
FROM
  hours
GROUP BY
  id,
  month
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/add36/5)